# Which MS-DOS game is this screenshot from?

Tags: game-identification, msdos

[image: MS-DOS screenshot - what is it from?]

From: 
https://archive.org/details/softwarelibrary_msdos_games/v2#contributors

This looks so familiar, but other than screenshot and the fact it is a DOS game, I have no other hints. Any ideas?

The given text is: "You are in a large cellar filled with barrels of foodstuffs."
Screenshot depicts this setting with a reddish floor and greenish hatch opening from it into the room (the way you came in, I'd assume), some red liquid or stain showing on the hatch door. The room is built of bricks. A small amount of green seems to ooze from one of the barrels.

Comment: Just so's ya know (may be of help in the future) you can now run Google searches by image :) https://images.google.com/imghp?hl=en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: There's also [an addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/googlesearch-by-image/) which adds a *"Google this image"* right-click option to images.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's from a game [The Hobbit from 1982](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Hobbit_(1982_video_game))

[Source](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/File:The_Hobbit_(1982_video_game)_-_cellar.gif)

Comment: And you can play it in your browser [here](https://archive.org/stream/msdos_Hobbit_The_1983/Hobbit_The_1983.zip?module=dosbox&scale=2)!

Comment: I understand Peter Jackson is planning a new version of this game which requires three browsers.

Comment: @Poldie, and it'll be 120Hz.

Comment: @PaulDraper Any news on Oculus Rift support ?